# How do I use MySqlParameterCollection.AddRange

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I've installed Connector/NET 6.5.4. In VisualStutio IntelliSense suggests a method called MySqlParameterCollection.AddRange, however there's no documentation available so I don't know how to use it. I've searched [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-net-ref-mysqlclient.html#connector-net-ref-mysqlclient-mysqlparametercollection) and found nothing.

**How do I use this method and where is the documentation?**

Comment: It's pretty much analogous to the SqlParameterCollection version: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e42546a - basically, it takes an array of DbParameter, in this case, MySqlParameter objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it this way

```
var myp = new MySqlParameterCollection();

myp.Add(new MySqlParameter(parameterName, dbType, size));
```

OR

```
MySqlParameter[] myArray = new MySqlParameter[] { new MySqlParameter(parameterName, dbType, size), new MySqlParameter(parameterName, dbType, size));

myp.AddRange(myArray);
```

Now you can attach it your Command object

Answer (score 9):

Because the MySqlParameterCollection derives from DbParameterCollection you could look at the examples for every other ParameterCollection. For example the SqlParameterCollection could be used in this way

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(pCommandText, GetConnection());
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
List<SqlParameter> list = new List<SqlParameter>();
list.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", value1));
list.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", value2));
list.Add(new SqlParameter("@p3", value3));
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(list.ToArray<SqlParameter>());
```

Comment: are there some braces missing?

Answer (score 3):

`AddRange` is normally used to add a collection of values.  In this case, I'm guessing it is expecting you to pass an `IEnumerable` of `MySqlParameter`.

e.g.

```
// List<T> implements IEnumerable
var list = new List<MySqlParameter>();
var paramCol = new MySqlParameterCollection();

// Add parameters to list
// ...

// Assuming param collection set up
paramCol.AddRange(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way of avoiding having to make a variable to hold the array of parameters

```cs
using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cm.Parameters.AddRange(
    new SqlParameter[] 
    {
    new SqlParameter("@TaskID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (int)dr["BSTaskID"] },
    new SqlParameter("@DateNow", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = DateTime.Now } ,
    new SqlParameter("@ExecDate", SqlDbType.DateTime) { Value = execDate } ,
    new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = (int)dr["BSUserId"] },
    new SqlParameter("@TaskParameters", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = parametersXML } 
    });
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

all in one fell swoop